# Argument cannot be accessed

Tags: c, pointers, operating-system, volatile, coverity

I am debugging a piece of code in coverity and I ran into an error that I cannot seem to find a solution to and it is related to side effect error since the variable was declared as volatile. The error is in the line:

```
DBG_SLOTS(TIMER_VAR_NAME.maximumS == randomNUM);
```

Error: Argument timerVar of _AssertImpl() has a side effect because the variable is volatile. The containing function might work differently in build.

The minimal reproducible code is given below:

```
typedef volatile struct
{
   uint32_t          maximumS;        // Maximum soft timer
   callbackEntry_t   callbackTable[ CALLBACK_NUM_MAX ];
} regression_t

#if (defined(ROM) || defined(RAM) || defined(DLE) || defined(BLLNK))
   timerVar_t TIMER_VAR_NAME;
#endif

uint32_t TServ_MaxInUse;

BackNum_t SEC SYS_Calls(uint64_t calls, PVFV_t callb, BOOL periodic)
{
   int runtimeTick = 0;
   TimeCallBackNum_t callbackNum;
   uint32_t intPosture;
     // ++++

  G_SLOTS(TIMER_VAR_NAME.maximumS == TServ_MaxInUse);
........
}
```

Comment: You may want to read this official help page: [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I suppose Coverity is complaining that the value might change while the assert is reading it, with unforeseen results.  How do you know Coverity isn't correct?

Comment: @stark That is why the value is made volatile right so that value stays intact while in debug mode. Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 5):

In C (and C++), accessing a `volatile` object is an operation that may have side effects.  Quoting C99 6.7.3/6:

> An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the
> implementation or have other unknown side effects.

Coverity is warning you that this assertion's expression accesses a `volatile` object, and consequently the possible side effect of doing so will not happen if the assertion is disabled, thus making your debug and production builds behave differently.

One way to resolve this would be to read the value into a non-`volatile` local variable first.  That is, instead of:

```
DBG_TIMER_SERVICES_ASSERT_MAX_SLOTS(TIMER_VAR_NAME.maximumS == debugTimerServices_MaxSlotInUse);
```

you could write:

```
uint32_t tmp = TIMER_VAR_NAME.maximumS;
DBG_TIMER_SERVICES_ASSERT_MAX_SLOTS(tmp == debugTimerServices_MaxSlotInUse);
```

That way, the side effect (if any) happens regardless of whether assertions are enabled.

That said, based on the names in the code, it seems clear there aren't side effects here (`volatile` is only being used to ensure the compiler understands that the value changes spontaneously), so I'd probably just mark this in the Coverity GUI as False Positive or Intentional and move on.